# How to create a toggle button to switch between panels

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my application I have 2 toggle buttons and 3 panels. **Button1** switches between **panel 1** and **2**. And **button2** switches between **panel 1** and **3**. I could make it work some how by giving `display: none;` property to div panels. but once it only works once for each button and then it makes all sub divs to `display: none;`
Have a look at the sample please:

```js
$(function () {
  $("button.panel2").on("click", function() {
    var visibleObj = $('.mainSection div:visible');
    if ($("div.panel2").css("display") == "none") {
      var inVisibleObj = $("div.panel2")
    }
    else {
      var inVisibleObj = $("div.panel1")
    }
    visibleObj.fadeOut(500, function() {
      inVisibleObj.fadeIn(500);
    })
  });
  
  
  $("button.panel3").on("click", function() {
    var visibleObj = $('.mainSection div:visible');
    if ($("div.panel3").css("display") == "none") {
      var inVisibleObj = $("div.panel3")
    }
    else {
      var inVisibleObj = $("div.panel1")
    }
    visibleObj.fadeOut(500, function() {
      inVisibleObj.fadeIn(500);
    })
  });
});
```

```css
div.app {
  margin:50px auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius:10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
div.app > .blur {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://goo.gl/0VTd9W);
  -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
div.mainSection, div.dashboard{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  text-align:center;
  color:#fff;
  font-size:20px;
}
div.mainSection{
  width:100%;
  height:85%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  top:0;
}
div.dashboard{
  width:100%;
  height:15%;
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
  bottom:0;
}
div.mainSection > .panel1,
div.mainSection > .panel2,
div.mainSection > .panel3 {
  width: 100%;
  Height: 100%;
  Background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}
div.mainSection > .panel3 > p{
  margin-top:80px;
}

.grid-button {
  background: none;
  border: none;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  position: relative;
  width: 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.grid:after, .grid:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 4px;
  left: 0;
  width: 32px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.grid.open {
  background-color: #FFF;
}
.grid.open:after {
  top: 10px;
}
.grid.open:before {
  top: -10px;
}

.grid.close {
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}
.grid.close:after, .grid.close:before {
  top: 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.grid.close:before {
  transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.grid.close:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="app">
    <div class="blur"></div>
    <div class="mainSection">
        <div class="panel1">
          <div>panel1</div>
          <div>panel1</div>
          
        </div>
        <div class="panel2" style="display: none;">
          <div>panel2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel3" style="display: none;">
          <p>Panel3</p>
          <div>panel3</div>
          <div>panel3</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard">
        <button class="panel2">button1</button>
        <button class="panel3">button2</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, each panel has some inner divs. the first time, it shows all inner divs. but once you switch between panels, it will not show inner divs inside. I tried to disappear the panels div only but it seems it does it for every div within that panel.

So any idea to keep make it work so switching between panels will not affect the inner divs?

Comment: it seems to get a bit mixed up logically when you're on panels 2 or 3 and you want to change, as both buttons change from panel 1 to something - why not three buttons, one for each panel, with each showing the panel it's assigned to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your javascript in this way:

```
$(function () {
    $("button.panel2").on("click", function() {
        var visibleObj = $('.mainSection > div:visible');

        if ($("div.panel2").css("display") == "none") {
            var inVisibleObj = $("div.panel2")
        }
        else {
            var inVisibleObj = $("div.panel1")
        }
        visibleObj.fadeOut(500, function() {
            inVisibleObj.fadeIn(500);
        });
    });


    $("button.panel3").on("click", function() {
        var visibleObj = $('.mainSection > div:visible');
        if ($("div.panel3").css("display") == "none") {
            var inVisibleObj = $("div.panel3")
        }
        else {
            var inVisibleObj = $("div.panel1")
        }
        visibleObj.fadeOut(500, function() {
            inVisibleObj.fadeIn(500);
        })
    });
});
```

The problem is in your selector `$('.mainSection div:visible');`. This select also the child div and when you try to show the correct panel the child div are hidden. If you use `$('.mainSection > div:visible');` you get only the direct child divs.